# Access EJB from JSF Bean in separate modules

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, ejb

I have a Java EE Enterprise application which comprise of EJB module and JSF based Web module. 
I have created EJB Stateless Bean, and now I need to call method of that bean from Web module Managed Bean, but compiler gives me an error.

I'm just starting with Java EE so I really don't have best of idea what should I look into

Comment: Just add EJB project to build path? Detailed answer really depends on development and build environment. Are you using Notepad + javac? Or Eclipse? Or Netbeans?

Comment: Netbeans in Ubuntu. I didn't install any plugins. Just plain Netbenas

Comment: I added the `[netbeans]` tag to attract the right folks. Sorry, can't be of further assistance. Netbeans is completely beyond me. But, to the point, you just need to add EJB project to the build path of the web project.

Comment: I wanted to make an object of EJB Bean, but it can't compile because "class doesn't exist"

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm just saying that I have no utter idea how exactly to set the build path right in Netbeans. I'm not a Netbeans user, so I can't tell the detailed procedure (click this, click that, blah) to achieve that. In any way, it ultimately boils down that you should achieve exactly the same effect as you would do in command prompt with `javac -cp [path to EJB classes]`. You're familiar with that, right? If not, then it would be so much harder to understand what such an IDE like Netbeans/Eclipse is all doing under the covers for you.

Answer (score 0):

So based on comments above I have solved this problem.
I went to web module of my application and to `lib` folder of it.

Right click -> add project

Found my EJB module and selected it. Not sure if this is good idea, but for now it seems it works.

Comment: misclick the desired project also possible to cause this.